# Opencart 1.5.6.4 - How to enforce telephone field length

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

People visiting our store enter telephone numbers in all formats including prefixing 0, 00, +(countrycode).

By default(and strangely) Opencart registeration field for telephone allows alphanumeric values upto 32 characters in length.

Could anyone guide how can I go about setting the length to 10 digits on registeration and checkout pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your `register controller` File. You can find your `register controller` file here `catalog/controller/account/register.php`

Then in this file you can see below function in this file.

```
protected function validate() {
```

You can change below code :

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
```

To

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 10)) {
```

You need to change validation message as well. Just open this file :
`catalog/language/english/account/register.php`

```
$_['error_telephone']      = 'Telephone must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
```

To

```
$_['error_telephone']      = 'Telephone must be between 3 and 10 characters!';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @ASG if this answer helpful then accept this answer, So Its useful to other SO user.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code in my website, what it's supposed to do is just accept numbers but this code allows alphabets to be written as well.